# How to send recorded voice in email?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, voice-recording

I am developing a Android Application, In which I need to send voice by email.
Ans I want that such flow,
record a voice and send mail as a audio file in attachment.
and I want that voice should not remaining in phone or SD card.
is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible but what have you tried? Have you searched to find out how it's possible to send *any* type of attachment by email? Audio is no more special than an image, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need, It works with me.......

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(YOUR_DIR, YOUR_FILE_NAME)));
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
    it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TITLE");   
    it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "CONTENT"); 
    it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    it.setType("audio/rfc822");   
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(it,context.getString(R.string.share)));
```

Comment: How will this delete the voice recording after it has been sent as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution according to me is..

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("audio/3gp"); 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send mail..."),0);
```

with above code you can send the voice as email attachment and in the onActivityResult() you can delete the file from sdcard/memory.

Comment: A 3rd-party email app isn't necessarily going to return a 'result' when called with `startActivityForResult(...)`.